# Dependency Injection with Grails Spring DSL

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, dependency-injection

When I use the Spring DSL provided by Grails is it possible to do constructor injection. If so, an example would be much appreciated.

If constructor injection is not possible, is there some other way that I can inject a spring bean without making the dependencies public properties. Using Spring in a Java project I can do this

```
class Foo {

  @Autowired
  private Bar bar
}
```

And it will autowire the `Bar` dependency either by name or type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to use constructor injection even using the BeanBuilder DSL

```
bb.beans {
    exampleBean(MyExampleBean, "firstArgument", 2) {
        someProperty = [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

whenever you want to reference other beans as constructor arguments, use the ref() method

```
bb.beans {
    exampleBean(MyExampleBean, "firstArgument", ref('anotherBean')) {
        someProperty = [1,2,3]
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html#14.4%20The%20BeanBuilder%20DSL%20Explained

Comment: This worked nice, but why doesn't `constructorArgs = ref('someBean')` work as well?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to [inject a bean into the constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) using the `@Autowired` annotation like you'd usually do in Spring. Here's an example:

```
class Foo {
    private final Bar bar

    @Autowired
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar
    }
}
```